# Effective combination algorithm to pass the time limit

Tags: c++, algorithm

I am doing a practice programming problem and got stuck to pass the time limit on this problem. Is there another effective algorithm to pass the time limit?

I have sorted the array, but I think this's still not helping much.

Here's my pseudocode:

```
sort boxA
sort boxB
for i in boxA:
      for j in boxB:
          if i+j < value:
              break
          else if i+j > value:
              count+=1
print the count
set count = 0
```

The question is asking to output how many combination of boxA + boxB that is greater or equal to the value.

Input:

```
5 3 1200                #number of boxA | number of boxB | value
100 110 160 750 1030    #number of boxA
400 500 500             #number of boxB
```

Output:

```
5
```

Explanation:
There are five ways combine boxA and boxB so that the value >= value

```
1. 750 + 500
2. 750 + 500
3. 1030 + 400
4. 1030 + 500
5. 1030 + 500
```

BoxA and boxB can have 500000 items in their list. I think this kind of test case that make the time limit on my algorithm.

Can you show another effective algorithm to pass the time limit for this problem? Thank you.

Comment: Have you considered using `<algorithm>` ?

Comment: yes, I have use std::sort to sort the array from the greatest value.

Comment: You can use bisecting the B box to reduce complexity from O(n*m) to O(n*log m)

Comment: There are plenty of other [useful functions](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/?kw=algorithm) in `<algorithm>`.

Comment: Don't go blindly browsing algorithms. Think about the problem first.

Comment: Your solution is wrong, what if you are looking for all combinations greater then 600? With your solution you will loose all combination with 110 and 160 since 110+400<600. You must sort boxB descending.

Comment: There is no need to walk through all elems in boxB for every elem in boxA if they are sorted. If they are sorted, then you know that boxA[i+1]+boxB[j]>=boxA[i]+boxB[j]. You can use that knowledge to optimize the inner loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each boxes with `a` items in A, the number of boxes in B that have number of items plus `a`, larger or equal to a certain value d  will be equal to the number of boxes that has number of items larger than (d - a).

So, first, sort array `B`, then for each box with value x in A, use **binary search** to find starting from which index in B, the item in boxes are larger or equal to d - x. Add in the final result (n - index) with n is number of item in B.

Time complexity is O(m log n)

Example:

We have two array A is {1,5,9,2,4,5} and B is {1,3,3,4,5,6,7,8};

We want to find the two boxes that has sum larger than 7 for example.

So, for each element in A

1 -> we use binary search to find index of the smallest element that greater or equal to(7 - 1) in B, which now at index 5, so the we add to the result (8 - 5) (with 8 is the number of element in B).

5 -> we need to find (7 - 5) in B -> we have index 1 after the search -> add (8 - 2) into result.

...

Comment: If you *also* sort A, then the binary searches for d-x in B don't have to start out considering the entirety of B: you only need to binary search within the subrange [0, last_binary_search_result] of B.

Comment: @j_random_hacker Yes, even we can do from the largest element of A to the smallest, which can early terminate the program .However, the additional cost is O(n logn), so it depends, I guess :)

Comment: I'm still a bit confused with this algorithm. Could you give me an example? Thanks!

Comment: Sorting array B takes O(n log n) time, so technically the entire running time is O((m + n) log n), or O(max(m, n) log n) if you prefer to write it that way.

Comment: If you want to optimize a little more, always choose the larger array as array A in this algorithm (that is, sort the smaller array, and then do a loop over the larger array with binary search of the smaller array).

Answer (score 0):

You may use something like the following: [Live example](https://ideone.com/dLr9iu)

```
std::size_t Count(std::vector<int>& A, std::vector<int>& B, int N)
{
    std::vector<int>& a = A.size() < B.size() ? A : B;
    std::vector<int>& b = A.size() < B.size() ? B : A;

    std::sort(b.begin(), b.end());
    std::size_t res = 0;
    for (int e : a)
    {
        auto it = std::lower_bound(b.begin(), b.end(), N - e);
        res += std::distance(it, b.end());
    }
    return res;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need the divide and conquer strategy. Suppose the ranges [b1, e1) and [b2, e2) are sorted, the following procedure does the work.

```
#include <iterator>

template<class It1, class It2, class T>
size_t do_work(It1 b1, It1 e1, It2 b2, It2 e2, T const t){
    if (b1 == e1 || b2 == e2) return 0;

    auto const n1 = std::distance(b1, e1);
    auto const n2 = std::distance(b2, e2);
    if (n1 > n2) return do_work(b2, e2, b1, e1, t);// always divide the shorter sequence

    auto const l11 = n1 / 2, l12 = n1 - l11;
    auto const l21 = n2 / 2, l22 = n2 - l21;
    auto const m1 = std::next(b1, l11);
    auto const m2 = std::next(b2, l21);

    if (*m1 + *m2 > t){
        return do_work(b1, m1, b2, e2, t) + do_work(m1, e1, b2, m2, t) + l12 * l22;
    }
    else{
        auto const _m1 = std::next(m1);
        return do_work(b1, _m1, std::next(m2), e2, t) + do_work(_m1, e1, b2, e2, t);
    }
}
```

If It1 and It2 are random access iterator, the time complexity is about O(n log2(n)), where n = max(n1, n2).

Comment: I hope you mean O(n log n) and not O(n^log2(n)). If it's really the latter, run as fast as you can away from the algorithm.

Comment: :-)  I thought that might be the case.

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume you can sort both arrays and that you can traverse each one either forward or backward.

```
sort boxA
sort boxB
let a = first number in boxA    // the smallest number in the set
let b = last number in boxB     // the largest
let total = 0
let subtotal = 0

while a exists
{
    while (b exists) and (a + b >= value)
    {
        let b = previous number in boxB   // "Move" the boxB iterator one place
                                          // toward the start of the array.
        let subtotal = subtotal + 1   // Now subtotal is the number of times
                                      // we have "moved" the boxB iterator since
                                      // the algorithm started to execute.
    }

    // Now subtotal is the number of numbers b in boxB such that a + b >= value.

    total += subtotal
    let a = next number in boxA
}

print total
```

If either `boxA` or `boxB` contains duplicate entries (the same numeric value more than once), "next number" means "next copy of a number", not "next unique number", and similarly with "previous number".

I could have written `while a exists` ... `let a = next number in boxA` as `for a in boxA` instead, but I wanted to emphasize the relationship between the way this algorithm treats `boxA` and the way it treats `boxB`: it iterates one time through `boxA` (in the forward direction) and one time through `boxB` (in the backward direction) *concurrently*.

In particular, unlike a typical nested loop control structure, we do *not* set the iterator over `boxB` "back to the start" for each new value from `boxA`.
Instead, during the entire course of execution of the algorithm the "inner loop" can iterate only as many times as the number of numbers in `boxB`.
The running time of the algorithm is therefore the time it takes to sort the two arrays
plus an additional O(n), where n is the size of the larger array.
Of course the worst-case cost if the algorithm receives unsorted arrays is O(n log n) due to the sorting, but it is still faster (by a constant factor) than an algorithm that requires an additional O(n log n) steps after the arrays are sorted.
And if we assume the arrays are already sorted (for some other reason), then the algorithm runs in just O(n) time.

**Update:**

As pointed out in the comments, if you know how many items are in `boxA` in the first place (easily determined in O(1) time for some data structures--in particular, the "array" in commonly-used languages), you can add logic that will break out of the `boxA` loop when all the numbers in `boxB` have been visited. Instead of iterating an additional `remaining_size_of_A` times, just do
`total += remaining_size_of_A * subtotal`. 
(Note that at this point, `subtotal` is equal to the size of `boxB`.)
This can save a few steps.

Comment: Your algorithm time complexity is O(nlogn + mlogm + (n + m)). You need to use some math formula as soon as the inner loop is end. `total += number of item left in a * subtotal` so the time complexity will reduce to O(nlogn + mlogm + min(n,m))

Comment: Yes, if I know in advance the number of items in `boxA`, you are right, I can skip Theta(max(m,n)-min(n,m)) steps at the end. What I wrote will work for any bidirectional data structure, however, such as a doubly-linked list. (Even for a singly-linked list, I just need another O(n) steps to make a reversed copy of it.)

Comment: Oops, scratch "Theta(max(m,n)-min(n,m))" from my previous comment. The sizes of `boxA` and `boxB` don't determine which iterator terminates first--what matters is the values of the numbers contained in the arrays. We could have 1000 elements of `boxA` and 10 in `boxB` and still never reach the beginning of `boxB` because after sorting, `(last in boxA) + boxB[5] < value`.